# Creating new blank activity using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-optionsmenu

I'm a new hand learning Android using Android Studio. While I follow the official tutorial [Getting Started](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#CreateActivity) provided by Google, I encountered a problem: When I trying to create a new blank activity, the default code in `DisplayMessageActivity()` is different from the sample. To be specific, there's just function `onCreate()`, but no `OptionsItemSelected()` and `class PlaceholderFragment` there.

I've tried to copy the code list below from the [Getting Started](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#CreateActivity),

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// Get the message from the intent

Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

// Create the text view
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setTextSize(40);
textView.setText(message);

// Set the text view as the activity layout
setContentView(textView);
}
```

however I still can't get the same activity (layout) of second activity: `DisplayMessageActivity`. 
There's just text but no top bar (consist of App's name, return button, etc.).

M.-J. Chiou

Comment: The tutorials are usually out of date with respect to the current shipping version of Android Studio.

Comment: Try this Link:[Tutorial Points](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_hello_world_example.htm)

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid: Thanks I'll try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a menu_display_activity.xml into the folder /res/menu like this one:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity">
</menu>
```

And add following to your DisplayMessageActivity.java :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_display_activity, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**EDIT:**

And don´t forget to add following code in your AndroidManifest.xml in your "application" - Tag:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I followed your instruction but still couldn't show the bar like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ItwoL.png)

Comment: Finally I found the blank activity default set `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` in AndroidManifest.xml so that I can't have **action bar**...lol Thanks a lot!